# How can I make a Card height extend based on content?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a `Card` which has a header and a grid view of photos. Below is the code:

```
_getImageWidget(Post post, AppConfig config) {
    if (post.photoPaths != null && post.photoPaths.length > 0) {
      var url = config.imagePathDomain + post.photoPaths[0];
      try {
        return Expanded(
            child: GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                shrinkWrap: false,
                children: post.photoPaths.map<Widget>((String path) {
                  return CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: url,
                  );
                }).toList()));
      } catch (err) {
        return Container();
      }
    }
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var config = AppConfig.of(context);
    return BlocBuilder<UserInfoBloc, UserInfo>(builder: (_, userInfo) {
      return Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Card(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30,
                  icon: roundImage(post.userPicture, Icon(Icons.person)),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                Text('@${userInfo.username}')
              ],
            ),
            this._getImageWidget(post, config),
          ])));
    });
  }
```

The header in the Card is a `Row` includes a `IconButton` and `Text`.
The body of the `Card` is a gridview which includes a few photo.

Below is the screenshot when I run the code. You can see that the photo is shown only a half. And I can scroll vertically on the grid view. The number of photos is dynamic which means there could be many rows of photos in the `GridView`. How can I make the `Card` extend based on its children?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a fixed size container and using the `BoxFit` property on the container.

Something like this :

```
new Container(
    width: 80.0,
    height: 80.0,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        image: new DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(url),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

**Edit** : Try to remove `itemExtent` from `ListView.builder`

Comment: I got an error `The argument type 'CachedNetworkImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'.`

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao try using `CachedNetworkImageProvider` i edited my reply.

Comment: I have tried you code, the error is gone but it doesn't make any different. The view is rendered as same as my code.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao alright try the following options and see what changes, use `Flexible` outside your `GridView`, or make the `GridView` a child of a `Container` or a `SizedBox` with a fixed height property, or set `shrinkwrap` to true and see the difference

Comment: I replaced `Expanded` with `Flexible` but it is still the same issue. I don't want to place a fixed height because the content is dynamic. Is there a way to extend the Card based on its content?

Comment: I know, but does it work if you give it a fixed height ? does it show correctly ?

Comment: I tried to use Container and SizedBox on top of GridView but none of them working. It gives the same issue. The Container and SizedBox need to be under `Expanded` or `Flexible`, otherwise it throws an exception.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao try checking if you have `itemExtent` in your `ListView.builder`, if so, remove it.

Comment: There is  `itemExtent: 100`. I got an error after removing it: ```'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1651 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true.
```.

Comment: So there is your problem you were forcing a height of 100, either try increasing the height a lot or update your code with the parent widgets so i can see more of the code.

Comment: How can I set an auto height in the list view? Or should I use a different widget as parent?

Comment: By removing `itemExtent` and having the parent widget have a fixed height

Comment: so you mean replace ListView with some other widget which has fixed height?

Comment: No have it inside a container with a fixed height or singlechildscrollview

Comment: I will get this error if I put a fixed height container as parent and remove `itemExtent` from list view. `'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 549 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
`

Comment: Is your Listview nested in another Listview ? did you try shrinkwrap to true ? seems to me that it has unlimited size and that's why there is an error, can you update your code with the parent widgets so i can form a proper reply ?

Answer (score 0):

By simply setting your `CachedNetwork` image to use a `fit: BoxFit.cover` that will resize to fill the content while preserving ratio (this means you may lose some of its details) or `fit: BoxFit.contain` that will try to be as big as possible while containing the entire source (image) within the bounds.

If that doesn't help as well (as I'm not seeing the entire tree so I'm not sure about the ancestors of your `Card`) you can also replace the return of your `BlocBuilder`'s child to be a `FittedBox` instead of a `Container` and apply the same logic for the `fit` property, but for the whole card instead.

Comment: I tried your option1, it only remove the space between images horizentally. It doesn't change vertical height. And I tried your option2, it gives me an error: `RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFittedBox#92258
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'`

Comment: Where did you place the `FittedBox`?

Comment: I put `FittedBox` under `BlocBuilder<UserInfoBloc, UserInfo>(builder: (_, userInfo) { `. It returns `FittedBox` instead of `Container`

Comment: What’s the ancestor of that `BlocBuilder`?

Comment: Its parent is `ListView.builder`